# Appyling one formula to excel table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, spreadsheet, vba

I have the following table:

[image]

I would like to calculate the interest rate that I would get for all combinations in this table. The formula I use is for example: `=$C$2 + $C$2*B3`

Please note, that this is just an example. My real table is much larger and doing it "by hand" would take several hours of work.

Any recommendation how I could do this fastly in excel?

I appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to put this in cell **C3** and fill to the right until the last column and then select the first row and copy/fill down until the last row:

```
=C$2+$B3*C$2
```

the principle is to lock the row for your main values in the second row by adding a **$** to the row number like **C$2** and you lock your column sign in the percentage column like this **$B3**. This will do.

There is a helpful tutorial on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NmVMjQzseLA) about cell references.